# Using case statement getting error as incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In store procedure I am placing code as

```
SELECT *
FROM [Order] O 
INNER JOIN Users U ON O.UserId=U.UserId
INNER JOIN State S ON S.StateId=O.Billing_StateId
INNER JOIN OrderStatus OS ON O.OrderStatusId=OS.OrderStatusId
WHERE (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Name,'')='' THEN 0=0  ELSE O.Billing_FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR O.Billing_LastName LIKE'%' + @Name + '%' END)
AND (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Email,'')='' THEN 0=0  ELSE O.Billing_Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%' END)
```

but it is giving error as Incorrect syntax near =

I dont know what I am doing wrong in placing THEN 0=0 ?

If it is wrong what should I wrote over there and is my query ok?

If @Name parameter is not there then it will not check 1st condition and will check for next condition

Comment: There are a couple of mistakes here. I think we can help you better if you explain what you want to do. I mean, what is you wanna get by this query.

Comment: I am implementing searching on list of items so I am just making query on he base of Name, email , state, city.  In case name is not there then it should check for other 3 item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR( O.Billing_FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR O.Billing_LastName LIKE'%' + @Name + '%' ))
AND (@Email IS NULL OR ( O.Billing_Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%'))
```

Comment: How about startdate and end date should I add in this condition? I mean if null then no codition else find the cindition

Comment: AND (@StartDate IS NULL OR ( O.OrderDate  >= @StartDate)) AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR ( O.OrderDate  <= @EndDate))

Comment: if parameter of @StartDate is define as date then this above code will work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Order] O 
INNER JOIN Users U ON O.UserId=U.UserId
INNER JOIN State S ON S.StateId=O.Billing_StateId
INNER JOIN OrderStatus OS ON O.OrderStatusId=OS.OrderStatusId
WHERE 
(NULLIF(@Name,'') IS NULL OR O.Billing_FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR O.Billing_LastName LIKE'%' + @Name + '%')
AND (NULLIF(@Email,'') IS NULL OR O.Billing_Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%')
```

Comment: 0=0 will return the boolean result and I don't think you can use the equal sign (=) after THEN keyword as there should be only a single statement without assignment or comparison etc.

Answer (score -1):

your **CASE** statement is wrong

in case condition you must define new parameter that will replace the condition.

see this (i dont know if its work or not)

```
WHERE
(CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@Name,'')='' THEN 0
    WHEN O.Billing_FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' OR O.Billing_LastName LIKE'%' + @Name + '%' THEN 1
 END as cond1) = 0 (*or 1, i dont know what you need)
 AND ........
```

Comment: Or condition is not possible in case statement like O.Billing_FirstName LIKE'%' + Name + '%' OR O.Billing_LastName LIKE'%' + Name + '%' this condition is not possible ?